# Is time dilation real or only imagination of the observers?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, time-dilation

As long as the time dilation is about what the observers think or see, there would be no great difficulty. But the assertions that the clocks run faster or slower cannot be justified.

Comment: Nature would beg to differ...

Comment: Time dilation has been observed in many, many actual experiments. You can measure gravitational time dilation for yourself, as the person in this link http://leapsecond.com/great2005/ did with atomic clocks purchased from e-bay.

Comment: "*But the assertions that the clocks run faster or slower cannot be justified.*"  .... what makes you think that?

Comment: What is the point of asking the question in the title if you are then going to reach your own (wrong) conclusion in the body?

Comment: It's an experimental fact. My favorite verification is the Hafele-Keating experiment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment

Comment: it is obviously unlogical that at the same time, both of the 2 clocks run faster than the other one. It is only possible if it is an observer-dependent appearance of reality. for example if a body approaches the  observer with v=0.5c , the observer would see 2 events with  "Δt'=2" , in only "Δt =1" hour

Comment: "Obviously unlogical" things are true on the regular, and "obviously true" things are often found to be false.  You just can't use your intuition on this one.

Comment: @user359498 if you think relativity says that each of two moving clocks ticks more slowly than the other, then you are wrong in a subtle but crucial way. If you would like to post a new question like the following, I will explain..Question: 'My understanding of SR is that each of two moving clocks ticks more slowly than the other, which is a logical impossibility. Where have I gone wrong in misunderstanding SR?'

Comment: In any case, if you are against my opinion that time dilation is only the observer's perception of time in the opposite system, you defend the contradiction that the clocks in the first system are slower than the second system, and in the second system slower than the first system!

Comment: As Einstein in " on electrodynamic of moving bodies 1905 " t is the time a light beam needs to reach the moving mirror, and that is t=x'/(c-v) and t'=[x'/2(c-v) + x'/2(c+v)] and the difference, t-t'= vx'/(c-v)(c+v). the rest are derived from the definition of time. The whole story is about a definition. And the result is: if we calculate the time acc. the definition, it would lead to a difference in the calculated time of an event calculated by an observer in two systems with relative velocity v.

Comment: The time dilation is not the result of observation of a physical phenomenon. This is a mathematical relationship disguised as physics.

Answer (score 5):

> As long as the time dilation is about what the observers think or see

It is not about what observers think or see. It is about how nature measurably behaves.

> But the assertions that the clocks run faster or slower cannot be justified.

It certainly can be justified experimentally. In the 1970’s Bailey et al sent muons around a particle accelerator ring. Counting the number of muons at the beginning and at the end gives you the number of half life times they experienced. Doing the same with muons at rest gives you a highly relativistic twin’s paradox. After each loop there were more high speed muons than slow muons, as predicted by relativity and as commonly described by the moving clocks ticking slowly.

Bailey et al., "Measurements of relativistic time dilation for positive and negative muons in a circular orbit," Nature 268 (July 28, 1977) pg 301.Bailey et al., Nuclear Physics B 150 pg 1–79 (1979).

See here for a comprehensive review of relativity experiments

https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html

Comment: if really the clocks run slower, it should apply to both frames without discrimination and logically it is impossible. Censorship does not belong to the lovers of science.

Comment: the root of the problem can be found in "On the electrodynamic of moving bodies " , where  Einstein derives the equation relating t and t'. Please  read again the 10 pages at the beginning of the paper

Comment: @user359498 said “logically it is impossible”. Things that actually demonstrably happen are clearly not impossible.